# How to solve error "Operand type clash: nvarchar is incompatible with nvarchar(32) encrypted with (encryption_type = ..."

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert, zapier

I am adding a new row from Zapier to their SQL Server app. The AlwaysEncrypted feature is enabled for one column in the table, but I get the following error when trying to perform an Add Row(Insert) from Zapier:

> {"message": "(pyodbc.DataError) ('22018', "[22018] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Operand type clash: nvarchar is incompatible with nvarchar(32)
> encrypted with (encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC',
> encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256',
> column_encryption_key_name = 'colEncrpyt',
> column_encryption_key_database_name = 'dbName') (206)
> (SQLExecDirectW)")...

The strange thing is, my datatype for the column that is encrypted is varchar. I also tried adding the "Column Encryption Setting=enabled" to the DatabaseName section of the SQL Server connection setup in Zapier.

Comment: are you using .Net ?

Comment: No, the workflow is housed entirely in Zapier. It triggers when a webhook from TallyFy is received that a form has been completed, I am then adding all data from the form to a DB table. The table has a single encrypted column 'TF_pName" which is set to DETERMINISTIC. That column is varchar(255).

Comment: when you have `Always Encrypted ` enabled , the  column is not simple nvarchar data type and in .Net It automatically encrypt the value you are passing , the problem you having is that the value you are passing is not encrypted varchar